# jquery not selecting the expected div element.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry

Evening,

I'm a bit confused about why some of my jquery isn't working.

Here's a proof of example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/FS34t/624/

As you can see, clicking on a 'box' triggers that alert.

However, when I attempt to implement this same behaviour into my own code, clicking a 'box' won't trigger.

```
function scroll(e)  { 
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
    var $items = $(balls());                               
    $items.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container
        .masonry('reloadItems')
        .append( $items ).masonry( 'appended', $items, true );
    });  
}  
}  
function balls(){
$iterator -= 1;
if($iterator < 0){
    var $boxes = $( '<div class="box">No more games!</div>' );
    $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes, false );   
    return; 
}
var $width =  9;
return (
    '<div class="box" style="width:18%">'
    +'<p>'+$test[$iterator][1][2]['name']+'</p>'
    +'<img src="scripts/php/timthumb.php?src='+$test[$iterator][2]+'&q=100&w=300"/>' //Replace this with the one below when timthumb is whitelisted
    +'<div id=boxBottom>'+Math.floor($test[$iterator][0]*100)+'%</div>'
    +'</div>'
);
```

I'm unsure of why

```
 $(".box").click(function(event){
     alert("TEST");
 });
```

Won't work here. 
My only guess is that it's because in the jsfiddle example, the 'boxes' are declared in the HTML, whereas these are generated in the .js?

Comment: You should make sure that you set the click handler _after_ you create the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run this code:

```
 $(".box").click(function(event){
     alert("TEST");
 });
```

before the `.box` elements are created and inserted in the DOM, then no event handlers will be installed because `$(".box")` finds no objects in the DOM (results in an empty jQuery object) to install handlers on at the time you run the code.

You have two choices to correct this:

1. You can switch to using delegated event handling so that objects created in the future will respond to events.
2. You can install the event handler AFTER you create a given `.box` element.

Delegated event handling (in jQuery 1.7+) would work like this:

```
 $container.on("click", ".box", function(event){
     alert("TEST");
 });
```

This attaches an event handler to the $container object (which already exists before the balls are created) which then watches for events that bubble up that originated on `.box` objects.

For versions of jQuery prior to jQuery 1.7, you would use `.delegate()`.

Comment: Both this and the other answer work. 

Which one would be better to use though?

Comment: This one would be the best! I'm going to delete my answer. If your using jquery 1.4.2 as it indicates in your jsfiddle, you should be using the .delegate() function.

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Just for future proofing. 

If I wanted to make a box with the class 'box'. 

But say I had a special box that had an id of 'special'

How would I adjust the answer you've given to accommodate behavior to only select the special id box? 

(Say I had all these boxes, and had 1 box that was to alert if clicked on)

Comment: @Adola - the second argument to `.on()` is the selector you want it to match to apply the event to those objects.  If you have an `id="special"` on the desired element, you can use `"#special"` as your selector in that second argument instead of `".box"`.  It's just an ordinary jQuery selector in that 2nd argument.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ahah!  Of course, pretty obvious now that I look at it. 

Thank you very much!